# List is not getting created in R.java

Tags: android, actionbarsherlock, r.java-file, roboguice, android-annotations

When I try to set an adapter to  list like `list.setAdapter(adapter);` I get an exception because list is null at this line of execution in FromPageActivity.java. If my understanding is right, since I am using Roboguice, @ViewById should initialize that in R.java.

**FromPageActivity.java**

```
@RoboGuice
@EActivity(R.layout.from_page)
public class FromPageActivity extends SherlockListActivity {
    @ViewById ListView list;
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        String[] values = new String[] { "Android", "iPhone", "WindowsMobile",
                "Blackberry", "WebOS", "Ubuntu", "Windows7", "Max OS X",
                "Linux", "OS/2", "Ubuntu", "Windows7", "Max OS X", "Linux",
                "OS/2", "Ubuntu", "Windows7", "Max OS X", "Linux", "OS/2",
                "Android", "iPhone", "WindowsMobile" };
        final List<String> ls = (List<String>)Arrays.asList(values);        
        final StableArrayAdapter adapter = new StableArrayAdapter(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, (List<String>) ls);
        list.setAdapter(adapter);
}
```

**StableArrayAdapter:**

```
public class StableArrayAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<String> {
    HashMap<String, Integer> mIdMap = new HashMap<String, Integer>();
    public StableArrayAdapter(Context context, int textViewResourceId,
                              List<String> objects) {
        super(context, textViewResourceId, objects);
        for (int i = 0; i < objects.size(); ++i) {
            mIdMap.put(objects.get(i), i);
        }
    }
    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        String item = getItem(position);
        return mIdMap.get(item);
    }
    @Override
    public boolean hasStableIds() {
        return true;
    }
}
```

**from_page.xml:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
              android:layout_width="fill_parent"
              android:layout_height="fill_parent"
              android:orientation="vertical">

    <ListView
            android:id="@android:id/list"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:clickable="true"
            android:text="@string/hello" />
</LinearLayout>
```

What am I missing out?

Answer (score 2):

You should set the id of your ListView with:

```
android:id="@+id/list"
```

The + symbol indicates that this is a new resource to be defined in your application's namespace, i.e. added to R.java. What you currently have:

```
android:id="@android:id/list"
```

...refers to a pre-defined id within the Android framework.

Answer (score 1):

There is a saying that, if you can't create file in R.Java, it means there is a problem with XML.

If you look at your listview, you have "android:id="@android:id/list", this should have been

```
"@+id/your_idname".
```

Hopefully this should resolve the problem.

Let me if its still not working!!

Answer (score 0):

@ViewById is not a RoboGuice annotation.  Looks like you're mixing your libraries.  You want @InjectView.